# How to disable spell-checking and auto-correction in Skype?

Tags: windows-10, skype, spell-check, autocorrect

I am using Skype (currently 12.13.257.0) on a German Windows 10 x64 machine.

**How do I completely turn off auto-correction and spell-checking?**

[These docs](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12411/how-do-i-disable-spell-check-in-skype-for-windows-desktop) claim I have to disable spell-checking in the Windows settings. I did so:

[image: spell-checking settings in Windows 10]

I have rebooted several times since, but it does not appear to have any effect on Skype:

[image: Skype is still using spell-checking and auto-correction]

(Note that *Brief* happens to be a German noun (always capitalized), and so is (with *much* goodwill) *Errors*.)

Even if the above is the (dysfunctional) official way, is there any inofficial way such as tweaking some registry settings?

Comment: I have been facing with the same, check my answer for temporary solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution doesn't seem applicable to Skype for Windows but in case of older Skype application (that you can also install on Windows 10) spellcheck would be here:

Tools/Options/IM and SMS/(uncheck) "Auto correct and highlight misspelled words"

You may need to check "show advanced settings" somewhere along the way.

Comment: I can't find "IM and SMS", nor anything like "Show advanced settings". I open my profile by clicking on the picture, then I click on *Settings* (as is described [here](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34664/finding-your-way-around-skype-for-windows-10)).

Comment: I am sorry, you didn't write Skype for Windows, but I see now it's in your link. This option can be found in standard Skype (you can install it on W10 just fine). Unfortunately I removed SfW from my computer because it was bricking offline to me, so I can't check there.

Comment: Well, I wrote I'm running Skype on Windows and also tagged the question with [tag:windows-10]. What do you mean by "standard Skype"? I mean the current version of the official Skype client, and the build thereof that runs on Windows.

Comment: There are currently at least 3 totally different Skype clients. "Skype for Windows" (I agree this name may be misleading in some context) is pre-installed on W10 and also downloadable from Microsoft Store. There is also Skype for Business and Skype. All of them work on W10 so tagging post as W10 is really not sufficient. Now I know I'm not answering your question but my advice, try using standard Skype - at least it's tested product and it's not "dumbed down" version (I installed SfW again to look for options there and options selection was... disappointing). Or Skype for Business.

Comment: "There are currently at least 3 totally different Skype clients." - wow. Way to confuse users. I totally wasn't aware of that (well, I do use "Skype for Business"/"Lync" at work, but it appears to be only "Skype" in name (i.e. you cannot add normal Skype contacts and vice-versa), so I don't consider it really comparable) and had assumed/feared the (presumeably one and only) official Skype client had generally been dumbed down like that. It's indeed not an answer to my question (which will have to remain open for the time being), but you did help me in that I've just switched to classic Skype.

Comment: Instead of apologizing for not reading the question correctly, edit your question, instead of leaving an answer that isn’t helpful unedited

Comment: O. R. Mapper, Skype for Business works with Skype contacts but it's up to administrator.(sometimes you need to wait 24h after adding contact because it throws errors)

Ramhound, great way to welcome newcomer. I edited my answer to my best idea of answer but honestly I should probably remove it (but then, comments are more helpful). But do me a favor, next time when you see someone new on site be kinder and don't attack them. Question mentions program version, but other than link to Microsoft website it only says "Skype" so it could also be improved and I don't feel that I deserve the blame.

Comment: @Chaosu: I have accepted this answer because I am meanwhile convinced switching from "Skype for Windows" to the standard Skype version is the (reasonably) proper solution to apply. I now also believe this answer matches the question, because at the time of writing the question, I was simply not aware of the distinction between Skype vs. Skype for Windows.

Answer (score 6):

In the new Skype there is currently no user switch. But you can go to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Skype for Desktop\resources\app.asar.unpacked\node_modules\@paulcbetts\spellchecker\build\Release
```

and rename there the `spellchecker.node` file to something like `disable__spellchecker.node__disable`.

Then restart the Skype and the auto correction feature will be disabled.

note: This fix may be need to be applied again after update.

Comment: Thank you. It is unbelievable how bad the new Skype is...

Comment: not applicable in 2021?